# Why is my rust program producing a Segfault

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault, compiler-optimization

I'm creating a particle-life simulation in rust and i'm using Nannou for rendering graphics. Everything seems to work when i run "cargo run" but when i tried doing a "cargo run --release" it sometimes produces a segfault, sometimes a blank screen and one time it worked. How is this possible?

Code to reproduce:

```rust
use nannou::prelude::*;

struct Model {
    _window: window::Id,
}

fn main() {
    nannou::app(model).update(update).run();
}
fn update(app: &App, model: &mut Model, _update: Update) {}

fn model(app: &App) -> Model {
    let _window = app
        .new_window()
        .view(view)
        .build()
        .expect("COULDN'T BUILD WINDOW!");
    Model { _window }
}

fn view(app: &App, model: &Model, frame: Frame) {
    let draw = app.draw();

    draw.background().color(BLACK);

    draw.to_frame(app, &frame).expect("Couldn't build frame");
}
```

Haven't got to refactoring yet.

I'm running the code on wsl2 Ubuntu.

I have tried running gdb on the binary produced but I realised that i had no idea what i were doing and it didn't help at all.

My graphics is running through wslg, I dont know if it uses x11 or wayland.

Running the repruduced example through gdb gives me:

```
Starting program: /home/tage/particle_life/target/release/particle_life
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff7b93640 (LWP 63758)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe7359640 (LWP 63760)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe6b58640 (LWP 63761)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe6357640 (LWP 63762)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe5b56640 (LWP 63763)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe5355640 (LWP 63764)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe4b54640 (LWP 63765)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcffff640 (LWP 63766)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcf7fe640 (LWP 63767)]
[New Thread 0x7fffceffd640 (LWP 63768)]
[New Thread 0x7fffce7fc640 (LWP 63769)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcdffb640 (LWP 63770)]
[New Thread 0x7fffcd7fa640 (LWP 63771)]
[New Thread 0x7fffccff9640 (LWP 63772)]
[New Thread 0x7fffabfff640 (LWP 63773)]
[New Thread 0x7fffab7fe640 (LWP 63774)]
[New Thread 0x7fffaaffd640 (LWP 63775)]
[New Thread 0x7fffaa7fc640 (LWP 63776)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa9ffb640 (LWP 63777)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa97fa640 (LWP 63778)]
[New Thread 0x7fffa8ff9640 (LWP 63779)]
[New Thread 0x7fff8bfff640 (LWP 63780)]
[New Thread 0x7fff8b7fe640 (LWP 63781)]
[New Thread 0x7fff8affd640 (LWP 63782)]
[New Thread 0x7fff8a7fc640 (LWP 63783)]
[New Thread 0x7fff89ffb640 (LWP 63784)]
[New Thread 0x7fff897fa640 (LWP 63785)]

Thread 1 "particle_life" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff738267d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. You shouldn't link to external services to provide your code in question. If you don't do this, prepare for having your question closed.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze, okay I will, but I don't know what a minimal reproducible example of my problem would be

Comment: @TageDanielsson the link Aleksander provided explains how you can get one in detail! Please make sure your example is **minimal** what you've posted now does not appear to be.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze okey, im reading that now, in the meantime I just put in all of my code. Hope that works

Comment: Since your program runs a GUI, you should also include information about your operating system/graphics server (like X11 or Wayland)/desktop environment, since those details might be part of "reproducing" your problem.

Comment: This is probably a bug in nannou. Safe rust shouldn't normally segfault

Comment: Try to run your binary under gdb to see where segfault is happening.

Comment: @totikom, I've now added the gdb output

Comment: @mousetail, yep. The code from example doesn't work with Vulkan directly and doesn't use any unsafe rust code. Therefore the problem is either in `nannou`, or in one of its dependencies, or even in system libraries.

Comment: The [nannou issue tracker](https://github.com/nannou-org/nannou/issues?q=is%3Aissue+segfault) has multiple closed issues regarding segfaults. Try checking if some of them might apply to you, even though they've been "fixed"

Comment: @TageDanielsson tread indices provide no useful information. When providing gdb output, please, run `backtrace` command to see call stack.